# Image has extra white space on left side. Anything helps

Tags: html

I have this invisible white space on the left of an image I can't get rid of. I've tried many things even the code below. I want the image to be able to cover the whole screen not have any white space around it.

```
html, style, body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

and still, get no results if anyone could help It would be very helpful.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Concert+One|Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
  /* TEXT SETTINGS*/
.text {
  position: absolute ;
  top: 15%; 
  left: 40%; 
  transform: translate(-30%, -50%);
  color: white; 
  font-size: 100px;
  text-size-adjust: auto; 
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

}

.text2 {
  position: absolute ;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10%;  
  transform: translate(0%, -50%); 
  color: black;
  font-size:90px;
  text-size-adjust: auto;
  font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;

}

.text3 {
  position: absolute ;
  top: 70%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(5%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-size-adjust: auto; 
  font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;

}

html, style, body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0; 
}

</style>  
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" >
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495741738915-f877fcd5f5f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80;" alt="Rocky Mountains"margin="0" padding="0" width="1360px" height="800px">
  <div class="text" >TEXT</div>
  <div class="text2" ><strong>TEXT</strong></div>
  <div class="text3" >TEXT</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code works on codepen -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQLqZQ did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: @Michi it doesn't work because if you make your screen bigger it will give the white spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
body *{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all I would recommend not to use inline css. But if you want no white sides add this to your css.

```
img {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}
```

this stretches your background and it won't repeat the image. This only works if you don't use inline css in your image otherwise use `!important` in the css